# iOS - UILabel with custom font and dynamic size

Tags: ios, uilabel, font-size

I am trying to create a UILabel in my iOS app that uses custom font. For that purpose I extended a class from UILabel and implementation looks like below:

```
@implementation CustomFontLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo" size:12.0]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo" size:12.0]];
    }
    return self;    
}

-(void)setFontSize:(int)size {
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo" size:size]];
}

@end
```

When I am using XIB, I set the label's class to "CustomFontLabel". I'm setting the font size to 26.
The problem is that as I coded to set the font size to "12" in code, its not picking 26.

Can some one point me where am I doing mistake for not taking font size as "26".

Comment: Thanks @borrrden You should have it as Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size will be set as part of the `initWithCoder:` method, so you should just use `self.font.pointSize` instead of `12.0`.